# Error creating bridge: Permission denied Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I trying run mosquitto on embedded linux device with configuration (show below) as root user and cmd: mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

```
### /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf ###

log_dest stdout
#mosquitto user
user mosquitto 
#bridge Config
connection 1234567890
address 192.168.0.101:1883
start_type automatic

topic # both 0

topic # both 1
#cleansession false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
#need to be false otherwise error on hivemq-side
notifications false

### end of conf file ###
```

mosquitto can't created bridge and I catch this log:

```
1472052730: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date 2016-07-05 08:47:49+0200) starting
1472052731: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1472052731: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1472052731: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1472052731: Connecting bridge 1234567890 (localhost:1883)
1472052731: Error creating bridge: Permission denied.
1472052731: Warning: Unable to connect to bridge 1234567890.
1472052761: Connecting bridge 1234567890 (localhost:1883)
```

However when I change user in conf file from mosquitto to root (but I know it's not correct) everything works fine. 
Can you help me resolved this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to bridge to the same instance of mosquitto? This is not going to do anything useful

Comment: I know but it is same, if I using some other address.

Comment: Also can you update the mosquitto console output to for when you run `mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`. I think this is going to be a file permission error for the persistence file for the bridge

Comment: I assume some systemcall is failing because of your permissions. Try running mosquitto with strace to find the offending syscall. If mosquitto is using several threads you might have to look at the -f/-F options. You can look for the syscall which writes the error message to the log and work back from that point.